# Bible Stories on LP from the 80s

Tags: bible

I am looking for the name of a set of records that I listened to as a child in the 80s. My parents bought it for me from Church. I want to say it was 8 records, but may have been 4 and I'm thinking 8 because I had to flip the record over. It was a complete old testament story for kids, with music. It told of the beginning, Noah's Ark, the burning bush, David and Goliath, The first Christmas. I believe it had The little Drummer boy song on it as well. It was narrated by a full cast of characters. It was very well narrated, more like a play. I believe the base color of the album was black and can recall and ark on the cover with many animals. The album cover had several flip pages that the records slid into that was also illustrated well and correlated with the stories. I have googled my eyes out and cannot find it. I would love to start my daughter on it. My parents paid $45 for the set in the mid 80s, so it was quite expensive back then

Answer (score 2):

It may have been "Your Story Hour," a small organization based in Medina, Ohio.  They aired their stories on radio and produced record albums, some of which are sold as vintage collectors' items on eBay today.  If buying their stories today, of course, one can purchase them on CDs.

Here is a link to their website:

https://www.yourstoryhour.org/

The ["Bible Comes Alive" albums](https://www.yourstoryhour.org/shop?page=3) cover the Old Testament Stories.  In their description, one may notice that they were produced by "Uncle Dan" and "Aunt Sue."  "Aunt Sue" passed away years ago, and was replaced by "Aunt Carol," so these are legacy stories.

If these stories are not the ones you were remembering, you might consider them as a possible replacement for what you are unable to find.  Another possible replacement would be with stories from ["Bible in Living Sound."](https://www.bibleinlivingsound.org) They are newer, and probably were never recorded on vinyl records, but they are also lively audio stories based on the stories of the Old and New Testaments.